# inbox stacking in phonegap-plugin-push

Tags: push-notification, phonegap-plugins, inbox

I am using Phonegap-plugin-push for receiving notifications in ionic app and I have done inbox-stacking. How will I identify if a notification contains n collapsible notifications or single notification. Currently, if I select collapsed notification, the action for last notification is getting executed.